# Break while loop using user input

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

how can I break out of the loop by user input example input other than yes will just break me out of the loop
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLuXh.jpg)

Comment: You have to include the code while you are asking the question. You should not be proving the image.

Comment: okay noted ,thanks for your advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```rb
def main
  loop do 
    # ...

    puts "Repeat for another input?"
    ans = gets.chomp
    if ans != "yes"
      break # will break the loop
    end
  end
end

main
```

Comment: It may read better to write, `break unless ans == 'yes'`. Though I wouldn't recommended it over `break`, you could write `raise StopIteration unless ans == 'yes'`. See [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).